# server side unable to capture append formdata files

Tags: javascript, php

I have a module where user can snap a picture (which will converted into a `base64 string` and then to a `file`), and I require to upload the file into our server, but after converted the `base64` into `file object` and append it into `formData` and submit the form. I found that in my backend, it unable to read the `$_FILES` property (refer last image), the array is empty but which suppose to have my file in there.

And checking on my `formData` variable, the data is append into it.

html

```
<form id="form" method="POST" action="smth.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  ...
  <!-- some other input information -->
</form>
```

js

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(){
  ...
  var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
  var base64 = $('#photo').attr('src');

  console.log(...formData);
  console.log('before checking');

  if(base64 != 'default.png'){
    var file = dataUrltoFile(base64, 'photo.png'); //external function to convert base64 into file object
    formData.append('photo', file);
  }

  console.log('after checking');
  console.log(...formData);
  ...
});
```

console
[image]

smth.php

```
<?php ... var_dump($_POST); var_dump($_FILES); exit(); ... ?>
```

result

[image]

Comment: You seem to be missing the part that prevents your form from submitting normally. Try adding `return false` to your `submit` event handler. You would then need to submit the form data programmatically.

Comment: Also `$(this)[0])` is much more concise as simply `this`

Comment: @Phil I try move my `$('#form')` js code into a button and then `$('#form').trigger('submit')`, still getting the same result, where in PhP my `$_FILES` remain empty.

Comment: @Phil could u make ur ajax suggestion as answer? so I can mark it as answer. Thank for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to attach your `FormData` instance to the existing `<form>` for a normal submit (*I think*).

If you want to mess with the normal submit, you'll need to add HTML elements into the `<form>` like `<input type="file">`.

Otherwise, submit the data via AJAX

```js
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', async function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  const formData = new FormData(this)

  // do stuff to formData

  const res = await fetch(this.action, {
    method: this.method,
    body: formData // automatically sets Content-type: multipart/form-data
  })

  if (res.ok) {
    // handle response
  }
})
```